# Show that there exists exactly one $T \in \mbox{Aut} \mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that given $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$ and $z_1,z_2 \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ there exists exactly one $T \in \mbox{Aut} \mathbb{D}$ such that $T z_0 = z_0$ and $Tz_1=z_1$.

In addition, describe the set $\{T \in \mbox{Aut} \mathbb{D}: Tz_0=w_0 \}$ given $z_0,w_0 \in \mathbb{D}$.

(This is not a hw problem; I am just trying to do it as an exercise.) Please help!

Comment: what do you mean by $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: unit disk! sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the identity function is one such $T$. So, your problem is to prove that if an automorphism of the unit disk has two fixed points, then it must be the identity.

Hint 2: reduce to the case where one of the fixed points is the origin.

Hint 3: use Schwarz lemma.